# Refactor .each where each is redirected into a hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

What would be the best way to refactor this :

```
@busy.each do |b|
  title =  b.title
  @events << {
    :id => b.id,
    :title => title,
    :start => b.busy_start_time(b.start_date,b.start_time),
    :end => b.busy_end_time(b.end_date,b.end_time),
    :allDay => false,
    :recurring => false,
    :color => 'black',
  }
```

`@events` is initialized as an empty array:

```
@events = []
```

And this busy statement is the SECOND of two pushes into `@events`.

I think that I can use map here something like :

```
@events = @events + @busy.map do |b|
  stuff
end
```

Because I don't want to overwrite `@events`, I want to add stuff into it.

But what I'm really searching for is a way to store the entire 'each' into a lambda and say something like :

```
@events += @busy(&:create_busy_hash)
```

And move all the hash creation into the `Busy` class as `create_busy_hash`

I'm still grasping lambdas and procs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is where you are trying to get to:

```
class Busy
  def event_info
    {
      :id => id,
      :title => title,
      :start => busy_start_time(start_date, start_time),
      :end => busy_end_time(end_date, end_time),
      :allDay => false,
      :recurring => false,
      :color => 'black',
    }
  end
end

@events = @busy_items.map(&:event_info)
```

Some additional notes:

- There is no need to initialize `@events` to an empty array, favor expressions over statements with side-effects (`map`, `select`, `reduce` and so on, instead of `each`).
- I renamed the variable to `busy_items` to emphasize it's a collection.
- `Busy` does not sound right for a class name. Classes are usually nouns, not adjectives. What's the nature of this class?

Comment: In this case the "Busy" class represents calendar events where the resource is "Busy", aka unavailable for a period of time that we would like to display on the calendar simply as "busy" much like Google Calendar does when you don't have permission to view details.  As such, while traditionally a verb, there is a precedent on calendar applications in Enterprises to simply display an event as 'busy'.  Hence, the name.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@events = @busy.map do |b|
  {
    id: b.id,
    title: b.title,
    start: b.busy_start_time(b.start_date,b.start_time),
    end: b.busy_end_time(b.end_date,b.end_time),
    allDay: false,
    recurring: false,
    color: 'black',
  }
end
```

?

Better still, take an object-oriented approach, something like `@events = @busy.map {|b| Event.new(b) }`, then define the constructor as appropriate.